# I am using Pywinauto GUI automation & facing errors with controls on the Adobe Acrobat menus or its submenus

Tags: windows, python-2.7, adobe, pywinauto

Below is a snippet of the code & the error message.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
pdf_file = "C:\\Users\\Test1.PDF"
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend='uia').start(cmd_line=u"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " +pdf_file)
appw = app.connect(title="Adobe Acrobat Reader DC").window(class_name='AcrobatSDIWindow')
app_menu = appw.child_window(title="Application", control_type="MenuBar")
app_menu.child_window(title="File").expand()

file1 = appw.child_window(title="File", control_type="Menu")
file1.child_window(title="Print...").click_input()
```

---

Error message:

```
raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Adobe Acrobat Reader DC', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

'''

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application

pdf_file = r"C:\Users\Test1.PDF"
acrobat_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

wpfApp = Application(backend=u'uia').start(cmd_line = acrobat_path + ' ' + pdf_file)
time.sleep(1)
wpfApp = Application(backend=u'uia').connect(path=acrobat_path)    # Reconnect

wind = wpfApp.windows()
title = wind[0].get_properties()[u'texts'][0]    # retrive Title of window
app_wind = wpfApp.window(title = title)    #get access tp main window
app_menu = app_wind.children(title="Application", control_type="MenuBar")   #get access to app menu
app_menu[0].children(title="File")[0].click_input()     #click on File Menu
file_menu = app_wind.children(title="File", control_type="Menu")   #get access to file menu window
file_menu[0].children(title="Print... Ctrl+P")[0].click_input()   #click on Print
time.sleep(5)  #wait for print dialog to open
```

'''

Comment: Thank you for looking to my code issues. Yes it works perfectly fine now! Thank you very much for your suggestions.